# Modify search form in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

i am new with wordpress.

I have modify search form in wordpress.

```
<form class="form-inline" role="form"  method="get" class="search-form" action="<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Type your search" value="" name="query" />
    </div>
       <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Search</button>
</form>
```

In this form i have modify name attribute of Search input box name='s' to name='query'.

But after that search is not working .

Do i need to write anything in function.php to Get query string.

Comment: In search form Search input box name must be `name='s'`.

Comment: @AkshayPaghdar: Do you mean there is no way to modify name="s" to anything.

Comment: I don't know about modifying, But that name `s` will be use in `WP_Query` arguments for search posts. so `name="s"` must need for search.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, i hope this will help you to workout,

Add this in theme's `fuctions.php` file:-

```
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'my_query_vars' );
function my_query_vars( $query_vars )
{
    if ( isset( $_GET['query'] ) && ! empty( $_GET['query'] ) ) {
        $_GET['s'] = $_GET['query'];
    }

    return $query_vars;
}
```